# How can I obtain a string representation of a Response object in the browser?

Tags: javascript, http, caching, encryption, service-worker

I am storing HTTP response object in a cache but it's in plain text. I want to store in encrypted form. I have used crypto algorithm but it's not working for Http Response object,

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

    // INIT
var myString   = "https://www.titanesmedellin.com/";
var myPassword = "myPassword";


// PROCESS
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(myString, myPassword);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, myPassword);
```

It's working with plain text but not working with the Response object.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to obtain the plain text body of a [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) in the browser, you can do so using the asynchronous [`text()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text):

```
const response = await fetch(someUrl);
const bodyAsString = await response.text();
```

You can then do anything you'd like with `bodyAsString`. The part about wanting to encrypt it doesn't change the answer to the actual question about obtaining the text.